# C syntax, please explain this code snip?

Tags: c, string

Can someone explain the code below?  How is it reversing the order of the chars in the string?

---

```
void reverse_string(char *str)
{
/* skip null */
if (str == 0)
{
    return;
}

/* skip empty string */
if (*str == 0)
{
    return;
}

/* get range */
char *start = str;
char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
char temp;

/* reverse */
while (end > start)
{
    /* swap */
    temp = *start;
    *start = *end;
    *end = temp;

    /* move */
    ++start;
    --end;
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: No, it's fairly good code by C standards. Pointer arithmetic - this is what you had to do. It even has comments to explain what's happening (which is rare in the C world).

Comment: Pointer arithmetic -something I have not yet covered. Hopefully exploring this bit of code can make that topic more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It swaps the first character and the last character. Then it swaps the second character with the next to last. And so on until it's done.

Comment: Thaks Dave, "swaps the second with the next to last.  And so on until its done"  Clarified!!!!!!!!  Nice!